# C# get the object only if it's different from bd's answer

Tags: c#, datagridview

So I have a button that shows all the items in db and a button that show a specific ones.

My question is, is it possible to not execute each time the query search, because it takes time even it's done in second thread.

For the first button i have

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table";
using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
            {
                this.cr.Add(new CrystalReport
                    {
                        item1 = dr["item1"].ToString(),
                        item2 = dr["item2"].ToString(),
                        item3 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["item3"].ToString()) ? "" : dr["item3"].ToString(),
                    });
            }
        dr.Close();
    }

dataGridView1.DataSource = cr.Select(r => new GridViewConstruct()
{ item1 = r.item1 , item2 = r.item2, item3 = r.item3}).ToList();
```

And for the second

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table";
using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
            {
                this.cr.Add(new CrystalReport
                    {
                        item1 = dr["item1"].ToString(),
                        item2 = dr["item2"].ToString(),
                        item3 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["item3"].ToString()) ? "" : dr["item3"].ToString(),
                    });
            }
        dr.Close();
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = cr.Select(r => new GridViewConstruct()
{ item1 = r.item1 , item2 = r.item2, item3 = r.item3 }).Where(x => x.something == something).ToList();
```

Is it possible to make it get if it's different from db?

Comment: You want just nothing to happen, if one clicks on your button ? Add `if (datagridView1.DataSource!=null) return; ` as first line to your click-handler, and that's it.

Comment: What is `this.cr`? Is it correct that your main goal is to only load the data once and rely on the data without retrieving them anew?

Comment: @Holger Not exactly I want nothing to happen if in db nothing is changed.

Comment: @Markus cr is an ObservableCollection.

Comment: @Cursed. The database does not inform you, when the content has changed. An SQL Trigger would do so, but EF does not support that directly, you had to implement something receiving the trigger event. As an intermediate solution, you could just run a smaller/faster query, that only finds out whether anything has changed. If the database does not change frequently this small query might reduce your delay. Another idea: You run the Query before the user asks for it  so in advance, every 2min in background. It will cause little more traffic in the network, but less delay experience for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd propose to load the data only once when the page is opened. You can move the data access code from the button event handlers to a shared method that fills the `cr` ObservableCollection. Ideally, `cr` should hold items of type `GridViewConstruct` instead of `CrystalReport`, e.g.:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table";
using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
            {
                this.cr.Add(new GridViewConstruct
                    {
                        item1 = dr["item1"].ToString(),
                        item2 = dr["item2"].ToString(),
                        item3 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["item3"].ToString()) ? "" : dr["item3"].ToString(),
                    });
            }
        dr.Close();
    }

dataGridView1.DataSource = cr.ToList();
```

Once the data has been loaded, you can initialize the DataGridView by assigning `cr` as data source.

You can disable the buttons until the data has been loaded and change the button code to use the prepared data that is stored in the `cr` ObservableCollection:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = cr.ToList();
```

---

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = cr.Where(x => x.something == something).ToList();
```

---

This is a viable approach as you need all records anyway; however, if you need to filter data, it would be the most efficient way to change the SELECT to include a WHERE condition and parameters.

---

The downside of this approach is that the data is loaded only once. However, there are several ways to refresh the data. The simplest one is to refresh the data after a time interval, but if the data do not change often, this leads to many redundant queries to the server. Hence, a push approach would be much better.
If you use SqlServer, you could use a [`SqlDependency`](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency?view=netframework-4.8) so that your application is notified if the data changes. Please note that this technology was developed for use in web or server applications where there are a very limited number of clients that listen for data changes.